# How can I enlarge my ZFS root pool mirror?

Tags: root, pool, mirror, zfs

I have a small system with two drives running Solaris 11 with a ZFS mirrored root pool.  I need to enlarge the root pool.  Can I just install two large drives, one at a time, waiting for each one to resilver?  Or will the first replacement disk have it's extra space ignored forever?  I know there is a property called "autoexpand", but I'm not sure how that applies in a mirror situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can enlarge a pool by `zpool replace`'ing the disks one-by-one with larger ones.  One possible gotcha is that you'll need to install grub on your non-boot disk so that you can boot the system when you're replacing the disk you normally boot from.  Also, you may need to change the boot order in the bios.